# Error launching PyCharm: failed to create JVM

Tags: pycharm, jvm

I edited the `pycharm64.exe.vmoptions`. Then I can not launch PyCharm, even after uninstalling, re-installing, and re-booting the computer. It keeps on reporting error.

[image]

How can I solve this problem and launch PyCharm? Thank you very much!

Comment: So what changes did you make to vmoptions?

Answer (score 0):

You have to reinstall jvm(Java virtual machine) then you have to set the path of the jvm.dll in Environment variable to do this [click here](https://www.simba.com/products/SEN/doc/5_Days_Guides/ODBC_in_Java/Non-SQL_DS/content/odbcjava/day1windows/setenvvar.htm) for help